# Ошибка линковки статической библиотеки: не удается открыть файл .lib

Tags: visual-studio, lib, cmake

Подключаю в cmake статическую библиотеку:

```
   project(protobuff)
    ...
    include_directories("D:/project/updater_proj/src/protobuff/protobuff-lib")
    ...
    target_link_libraries (protobuff libprotobuf)
```

на что компилятор ругается:  fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "libprotobuf.lib"

В чем ошибка? Видит но не может открыть? Или совсем не видит? и как правильно подключить статическую библиотеку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) это команда для компилятора, которая указывает ему где ему искать заголовки(дополнительно). Вам нужно использовать команду [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html):

```
link_directories("D:/project/updater_proj/src/protobuff/protobuff-lib")
```

или же напрямую указать:

```
target_link_libraries (D:/project/updater_proj/src/protobuff/protobuff-lib/protobuff.lib)
```

---

А вообще, по уму, это делается по другому:

```
find_package(protobuf REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Вот и всё. Какие требования есть у поиска данного пакета можно посмотреть [тут](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindProtobuf.html)

Comment: последняя ссылка очень порадовала! Пасиб!

Answer (score 2):

Команда `include_directories` используется для указания директорий, в которых компилятор будет искать заголовочные файлы. Для указания директорий поиска библиотек можно использовать [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html). Либо использовать абсолютные пути (предпочтительный способ).

Если линкуемая библиотека внешняя (то есть не один из ваших таргетов), то используйте импорт:

```
add_library( lib STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Path_to_lib} )
```

Либо используйте [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).